# How to solve this operator equation?

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory

May be $\alpha(t)$ a **non-invertible** Operator on a Hilbert space for a real-valued Parameter $t$. Also, let be $A(t),B(t)$ arbitrary Operators also dependent on $t$ and $f(t)$ an $L^\infty$-integrable function. How can I solve the following Operator equation

$\alpha(t)(\frac{d}{dt}-A(t))f(t)=B(t)f(t)$?

My thoughts: I know that the solution of the Operator equation $(\frac{d}{dt}-A(t))f(t)=0$ is given by the parameter-ordered exponential in $A(t)$. But the Problem is that $\alpha(t)$ cannot be inverted.

Can I alternatively solve the generalized Eigenvalue Problem $det(\alpha(t)(\frac{d}{dt}-A(t))-B(t))=0$ so that I can obtain the "eigenvectors" $f(t)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a generalized eigenvalue problem approach would be the way to go, as this is typically the approach when one of the associated operators is non-invertable.

The problem would take the form of:
  $$
\det\left(\alpha\!\left(t\right)\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}-\mathbf{A}(t)\right)-\mathbf{B}(t)\right)=0
$$

The determinant being a functional determinant in this case.

Solving this will give you the eigenvalues of the operator, which you can then use to get the eigenvectors.